# How should I locate NDK on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-ndk

I know there isn't any code here but it is an issue I'm having in relation to running my code. 
I'm making a game for android and received code to build on. The person who gave this code to me wrote instructions for Mac and I've been able to follow them until now where he tells me to execute commands in "Terminal" which I know is for Mac. I have Windows and don't know how I should go about following these steps. They are as follows:

```
 11. Open terminal and execute following commands

  i. export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/josip04/Development/adt-bundle-macx86_
  64-20130729/sdk"

  ii. export NDK_ROOT="/Users/josip04/Development/android-ndk-r9c"

 12. In terminal navigate to:
 “/Users/josip04/Desktop/game_big_crocodile_android/games/game_big_crocodile/pr
 oj.android” and execute the following: “./build_native.sh”
```

NOTE: I have Windows 7
Thank you so much for all your help! I highly appreciate it! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, if your question is about Windows, tag it as such (rather than `osx`). Also, you need to tell which version of Windows you are using.

Comment: @shoerat Thank you very much for the tips! I've taken your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your actual question is "How do I add Android SDK and NDK to Windows path?". This is easy and straightforward:

1. Go to `Control Panel > System and Security > System` (alternatively, you can press <kbd>Windows + Pause</kbd>)
2. Press `Advanced system settings` menu from left pane.
3. Click on `Environment Variables...` button.
4. Select "PATH" from `User variables for ...` and press `Edit...` button.
5. Add the location of Android SDK and NDK installed on your machine at the end of `Variable value:` field.

In step 4, if there is no "PATH" variable, press `New...` button and put `PATH` to `Variable name:` field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not solve my problem but it did help me because this was one of the steps. If anyone else is having this problem, you need to complete the commands in Cygwin Terminal (download it). The terminal works just like that of a Mac's. I can't upvote because I don't have 15 rep but thank you very much for helping me :)